# Unexpected behavior of pytorch module with a dict of buffers when moving it to cuda

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a pytorch (version 1.10.0+cu111) module where a dict of tensors are registered as buffers. Everything looks fine at first and I can access a tensor in that dict both via that dict or via the registered name:

```py
class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()

        self.tensor_buffer_dict = {
            'a': torch.randn(10),
        }

        for k, v in self.tensor_buffer_dict.items():
            self.register_buffer(f'buffer_{k}', v)


model = MyModel()
print(id(model.buffer_a))
print(id(model.tensor_buffer_dict['a']))
# output is
# 140361680762656
# 140361680762656
```

But after the model is moved to cuda they are no longer the same:

```py
model.cuda()
print(id(model.buffer_a))
print(id(model.tensor_buffer_dict['a']))
# output is
# 140361680361968
# 140361680762656
```

Since both `model.buffer_a` and `model.tensor_buffer_dict['a']` refer to exactly the same tensor before moving to cuda, how come they become different afterwards?